# Phpmailer not responding

Tags: mobile, phpmailer

I am using the PHPMailer class to send email with attachments. The mail 
sends successfully but the $mail->Send() method doesn't return when i am 
connected to mobile packet data. ie i dont get the succeed or failed message. Interestingly the code works fine when i am connected to Wifi DSL line. My script is....

```
require ("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS'; 

$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";  
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Username ="xxx"; 
$mail->Password = "xxx"; 

$mail->SetFrom("from@mydomin.com","my name");
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi";
$mail->AddAddress("tomail@otherdomain.com");
$mail->AddBCC("tomail@otherdomain.com");

$file1 = "path/to/file1.pdf";
$file1 = "path/to/file2.pdf";
$file1 = "path/to/file3.pdf";

$mail->AddAttachment($file1);
$mail->AddAttachment($file2);
$mail->AddAttachment( $file2);

if(!$mail->Send())
{

    echo "succeed";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "*doesnt return*"? The code is stuck or returns failure?

Comment: try putting `$mail->Send()` inside a `try{ }catch{ Exception $e}` and print any exception/error it might throw

Comment: Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;` to show what's happening during the connection. Catching exceptions will only show you the end result, not the cause, and you need to enable them by passing `true` to the constructor anyway.

Comment: Also set `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` - it's case-sensitive. You've based your code on an obsolete example, so you're probably using an old version of PHPMailer too - update to the latest version.

Comment: the code stucks...returns nothing.. I put try catch block but still i get nothing.. neither from catch block nor from finally